# A weird situation happened to my Terminal,relative to texlive

Tags: ubuntu, latex, terminal

Right now I found that when I open my Terminal, it always shows those message:

```
bash: /usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf/doc/man:: No such file or directory
bash: /usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf/doc/info:: No such file or directory
```

I don't know where is the wrong. Even I am not sure what I did to give rise to this situation.
I have checked texlive, it can compile tex file as normal.

Please tell me what is the meaning of the messages arising in terminal and how can I cancel it?

my system is ubuntu 12.03 , and  texlive 2012 installed.

Do I need to offer more information on my setting to deal with my problem?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about tex, but too old to migrate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this problem by myself.

I found that some codes about texlive2012 in `/etc/bash.bashrc` are messed up. I mended them and now those messages disappears.

The solution is to add those codes into `/etc/bash.bashrc` , which follows the guide from texlive manual.

`PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2012/bin/i386-linux:$PATH; export PATH`

`MANPATH=/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf/doc/man:$MANPATH; export MANPATH`

`INFOPATH=/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf/doc/info:$INFOPATH; export INFOPATH`